# Unity - Why is my Material on a GameObject black?

Tags: unity-game-engine

### Unity

I added a .PNG-File in my Textures-Folder and then make a material out of it in my Materials-Folder and then I add this material to a GameObject in the current Scene, but the Material on the GameObject don't look like the preview. It's only black.[Look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRe19.png)

I'm frustrated, can anyone help me?

[Lightning Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAuck.png)[Lightning Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NeJ1.png)

Comment: Change the shader of the material to `Sprites/Default`. You can find it by clicking on the `Legacy Shaders/Diffuse` dropdown under the `SpriteRenderer` component

Comment: Now, the GameObject has the same color as the other without a Material. But not the material look.

Answer (score 1):

Your scene probably have no light on it.
Maybe you should add a light source or re-activate the ambient light by going in: **Window** -> **Rendering** -> **Lightning Settings** and update the **Environment** -> **Intensity Multiplier** value to 1 or something else you like.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I added a directional light to my Scene, but the problem isn't solved yet. And I went into the Lightning Settings and followed your steps, but nothing happened.

Comment: What version of Unity are you using?

Comment: Unity 2018.4.0f1

Comment: I tested everything in a 3D project. Tonight I will try to simulate this same environment in a 2D project to see if I can reproduce this bug, then I hope to help you fixing it.

Comment: That would be nice

Answer (score 1):

It's because the game object which you have imported from blender is not uv unwrapped. You have to  unwrap the game object first and then import the game object and texture in the unity and drag the texture on the game object.